# Calling the proper constructor based on input length

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

I have a `Point` class.

The point can be both in 2-D and 3-D. I am deciding this based on the length of the coordinate array passed to the constructor.

```
    double x, y, z;
    int dimension;
    Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        dimension = 3;
    }
    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = 0;
        dimension = 2;
    }
    Point(double[] p)
    {
        if(p.length == 2)
            this(p[0], p[1]);
        else if(p.length == 3)
            this(p[0], p[1], p[2]);
    }
```

The last constructor gives error because *constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor.*

Is there a way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: Why not make a Factory method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can do something like

```
double x, y, z;
int dimension;
Test(double x, double y, double z) {
    initDim(x, y, z);
}
Test(double x, double y) {
    initDim(x, y);
}
Test(double[] p)
{
    if(p.length == 2)
        initDim(p[0], p[1]);
    else if(p.length == 3)
        initDim(p[0], p[1], p[2]);
}
private void initDim(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    dimension = 3;
}

private void initDim(double x, double y) {
    initDim(x, y, 0);
    dimension = 2;
}
```

Comment: That's a perfect idea. Thank you!

Comment: @Sajan i think from `initDim(double x, double y)` you can call `initDim(double x, double y, double z)` by passing `0` as the last argument. Just to avoid repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to those i would like suggest a solution like this. Less constructors and easily adaptable. Bit similar to what you do to create a singleton.

```
public class Point {
    double x, y, z;
    int dimension;

    private Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        dimension = 3;
    }

    private Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = 0;
        dimension = 2;
    }

    public Point getInstance(double x, double y, double z) {
        return new Point(x, y, z);
    }

    public Point getInstance(double x, double y) {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getInstance(double[] p) {
        if (p.length == 2)
            return new Point(p[0], p[1]);
        else (p.length == 3)
            return new Point(p[0], p[1], p[2]);         
    }
}
```

You can create your instance like this.

```
Point point = Point.getInstance(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not good to have too many constructors. It gives you a good opportunity to express how it should be used.

```
public static Point Create(double... p)
{
    if(p.length == 2)
        return Point(p[0], p[1]);
    else if(p.length == 3)
        return Point(p[0], p[1], p[2]);

    // default case or throw error
}
```

Alternatively you can create an `initialize` method, which you call from the constructors.